# C++ Function with pointer as parameter and Handle it with swig interface

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig, freeimage

I have created swig interface file to create JNI for my C++ Files. but some of my C++ Files include functions which accept pointer as argument like (void*) , C++ BOOL and Swig converts it into 
type like **SWIGTYPE_p_int32_t** how to pass such kind of data type from java ?

for example one of the function's actual prototype is like below in C++

```
DLL_API void DLL_CALLCONV FreeImage_Initialise(BOOL load_local_plugins_only FI_DEFAULT(FALSE));
```

which is converted in Java file with swig

```
public static void FreeImage_Initialise(SWIGTYPE_p_int32_t load_local_plugins_only)
```

how to pass such value from java ?

I have many classes which include such kind of arguments in function.
is there any way so that I can apply solution to bulk files for handle datatype as simple as possible.

I have read one way to do that is create helper function but I cannot go for it because i have many c++ classes and for each and every function creating helper function for returning pointer is not way to go.

Please suggest any other way if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved myself. Swig was not be able to recognize all the typedef in header files and hence it was producing that kind of Types in wrapper. I need to redefine them in Interface file.

Comment: SWIG doesn't recurse into #include definitions by default, and you normally don't want it to.  See my answer for letting SWIG know about Windows types such as BOOL.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the weird declaration of `BOOL` type.

In this particular case, you can pass an `int` there from Java side. Either `0` or `1` will do the right job.

Or you can change `BOOL` to `bool` in your native code by creating a small wrapper for this library.

Comment: I am unable to use 0,1 from java side in place of SWIGTYPE_p_int32_t. and What about case where function is returning SWIGTYPE_p_int32_t and void* kind of pointers ?

Comment: But you can patch this type to a simple ``int``. If your functions return ``void*`` you cannot do much with it in Java. However, you can store it in ``int`` and pass it back to native code where it accepts ``void*``.

Comment: I can patch it for one function sir but I am trying to create wrapper of third party library which include these type at many places in the code not just single function.

Comment: You can ``#define SWIGTYPE_p_int32_t int``

Answer (score 0):

About booleans, I would recommend using `bool`instead of `BOOL` because JNI directly provides a type signature for it: `Z` (you can check signatures at: [JNI Types and Data Structures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html))

About pointers, if are pointer to basic types, this is declared by adding `[`in front of corresponding signature, this is: `int* --> [I`. If it's a pointer to a own class, swig will create a fully qualified class.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

SWIG doesn't know about windows types.  Add `%include <windows.i>` to the interface definition.